# Get executemany to accept Unicode strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, pymssql

How can one get executemany to format a prepared SQL to write unicode data?

I have a prepared query that is similar to this:

```
insert into foobar select(select baz.somestring from baz where baz.whatever = %s ), %s
```

Changing the %s directly into something like N'%s' in the prepared query won't work, how do i get pymssql to encase my inputs with N'mystring' instead of a simple 'mystring'?

The current behaviour results in questionmarks in the table when something like a \u5000 comes around, for example, while it should save the \u5000 or any other unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i get pymssql to encase my inputs with N'mystring' instead of a simple 'mystring'?

pymssql will do that if you create a proper parameterized query:

```python
print(sys.version)  # 3.7.2 ...
print(pymssql.__full_version__)  # 2.1.4
#
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM #tmp WHERE whatever = %s"
params = ('Ώπα',)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
print(crsr.fetchone())
```

SQL Profiler shows that the query is sent as

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM #tmp WHERE whatever = N'Ώπα'
```